# Generating PDF containing SVG images using Apache FOP in an Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, svg, oracle11g, apache-fop

I am trying to generate PDF documents inside an Oracle 11g database using Apache FOP. I have installed the classes from the following JAR files into my schema, using the **loadjava** tool:

1. commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
2. commons-io-1.3.1.jar
3. avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
4. xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
5. xalan-2.7.0.jar
6. serializer-2.7.0.jar
7. xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar
8. batik-all-1.7.jar
9. fop.jar

While inside the database, I can generate PDF documents without graphics. The same code outside the database (command-line) creates PDF documents with all the relevant graphics.

The inline SVG graphics seem to simply be ignored while executing within the database. Outside the database they are rendered correctly by Batik.

Have you successfully used Apache FOP to generate PDF documents containing SVG graphics, in an Oracle database? What suggestion(s) can you make?

I have one graphic defined as `<fo:external-graphic content-width=".5in" content-height=".5in" src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA..." />`. This renders correctly outside the database, and causes a permission error while executing within the database:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission 
(java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader) has not been granted to 
ProtectionDomain  (null <no signer certificates>)

com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl$TransletClassLoader@98644313
 <no principals>
 java.security.Permissions@b0558743 (
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)  
(java.lang.RuntimePermission createSecurityManager)  
(java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThread)  
(java.lang.RuntimePermission preferences)  
(java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)  
(java.util.PropertyPermission user.language write)  
(java.util.PropertyPermission * read)  
(oracle.aurora.security.JServerPermission LoadClassInPackage.*)
)
```

Within the database, I know how to grant permissions to my **schema**; however I don't know how I would grant *getClassLoader* to the codebase I loaded.

**NOTE**: changing the url of the inline graphic above to explicitly ask for 
**url('** data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA... **')** seems to have fixed the problem for this image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I determined the problem with the `<fo:external-graphic />` inline image: the problem was with the **src** attribute, which originally was specified without **url('...')** . Adding url() to the **src** attribute makes the image resolve when running in the database.

I am still unable to get the inline SVG graphics to render when running in the database.